# I am puzzled about the difference between these two situations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

A block of mass $m=20kg$ stands on a frictionless horizontal surface. It is pulled by a rope, which passes through an ideal pulley.  The rope is connected to a lifting block with a weight of $W = 50N $, and in another case, the rope is pulled by a force of F  = 50N.What is the difference between these two situations

Comment: What makes you think there is any difference between the two figures if F=W?

Answer (score 1):

The tension in the string is smaller in the first case.  In the second case $T=F=30$N independent of the acceleration $a$. In the first  case $Wa= Wg-T=30{\rm N}-T$ so $T= 30{\rm N}-Wa$ which is less than 30N.

Comment: Why are you multiplying weight term with acceleration again? Weight is force (30N) not mass as given in question.

Answer (score 0):

This classic problem can be solved by simple FBD, and Newton's second law.

**First Case**
For first block:
$$W-T=\frac{Wa_1}{g}$$

Where $a_1$ is acceleration of whole blocks system. Now here $W=m_0g$ , where $m_0$ is mass of 1st block.

For second block:
$$T=ma_1$$

So you can find accleration now.

**Second Case**

Here force applied is our tension $F=T$
And for our block
$$T=ma_2$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the $30$ N force has to accelerate both the mass $m$ and the weight $W$ which has mass $30/g$.

In the second case the $30$ N force is accelerating the mass $m$ alone.